# Error when I try to simulate my app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I click the button start, emulator doesn't work. What can I do? Pls help me! This is the error:

What can I do? Pls help me!

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\Users\VicenÃ§\Android\Probeta\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug: file not found
    at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
1 error; aborting

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

  > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
  >   C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Vicenç\Android\Probeta\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Vicenç\Android\Probeta\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
  >   Error Code:
  >   1
  >   Output:

  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\Users\VicenÃ§\Android\Probeta\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug: file not found
      at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
      at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
  1 error; aborting
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.35 secs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your project path name, android studio can't recognize some special characters, maybe the problem because of these letters **Ã§**